# Ref parameters not changing value? c#

Tags: c#, function, parameters, reference

I'm currently writing a simple program for college work, and using a function to detect characters in a string and remove them, the function is supposed to output a bool and the new string is supposed in a reference parameter however the reference parameter isn't working and data isn't being carried over?

```
    public static bool DetectAndRemoveCharacter(ref string Word, char Character)
    {
        bool returnVal = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < Word.Length; x++)
        {
            if (Word[x] == Character)
            {
                Word.Remove(x, 1);
                returnVal = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

The bool is returned but (Letters) is not being altered, It could be something simple, but I didn't think refs would to be too complicated to use, I could try and fix it with return object lists, but it would be much simpler if I could accomplish it this way.

```
Set = DetectAndRemoveCharacter(ref Letters, '?');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable objects and cannot be changed. The method `Remove` does not chcange the original object, you have to reassign the result to the variable:

```
Word = Word.Remove(x, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in `.net`.  This means that every time you alter a string, a new string is returned. The original string is not altered.  Your code is not capturing this.

Try:

```
public static bool DetectAndRemoveCharacter(ref string Word, char Character)
{
    bool returnVal = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < Word.Length; x++)
    {
        if (Word[x] == Character)
        {
            // assign value here
            Word = Word.Remove(x, 1);
            returnVal = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```